# how to use HashMap in POJO class and retrieve it?

Tags: java, hashmap

where should i write the hashmap in my POJO?

i've tried on my constructor, I don't know how to use the hashmap?
especially in my POJO class -->

```
public class CurrentAttendance {

    private String name;
    private int userCount;
    private int currentAttendance;
    private long firstJoin;
    private Object timestamp;

    //empty constructor
    public CurrentAttendance() {
    }

    //entry values
    public CurrentAttendance(String name, int userCount, int currentAttendance, long firstJoin, Object timestamp) {
        this.name = name;
        this.userCount = userCount;
        this.currentAttendance = currentAttendance;
        this.firstJoin = firstJoin;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

this is my getter

```
    public String getXName(){
        return name;
    }
    public int getUserCount(){
        return userCount;
    }
    public int getCurrentAttendance() {
        return currentAttendance;
    }
    public long getFirstJoin(){
        return firstJoin;
    }
    public Object getTimestamp(){
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```

Comment: What hash map?  I see no such object.  Are you asking about the hashCode method you can override from java.lang.Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing.

Do you want to have a HashMap private data member?  You can always do this:

```
public class CurrentAttendance {
    private Map something = new HashMap();

    public Map getSomething() { return Collections.unmodifiableMap(this.something); }
}
```